# UITableView's ScrollsToTop not working when table view is below y = 0

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` as a subivew of another view. The tableView is located beaneath y = 0 in relate to its parent view. As a result - if I'm right - the automatic `scrollsToTop` does not work.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` is a `UIScrollView`, so if you want to scroll to top you could always call `setContentOffset:animated:`

```
// Swift
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)

// Objective-C
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated: YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps I wasn't clear enough: the thing is that I want it to be triggered in repsonse to status bar tap. And that's not trivial to detect.

Comment: I see. When you have multiple scroll views in your view hierarchy it becomes trickier. Is this the case for you?

Comment: Ok, I have just managed to solve the problem now. So there was one more Scroll View in that screen which I did not think about - changing its scrollToTop property to NO solved it.
Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Cool! For future reference though, [The doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollsToTop) states that `...the system asks the scroll view closest to the status bar to scroll to the top.`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. 
Apparently there was one more `Scroll View` in that screen which I did not think about - changing its `scrollToTop` property to `NO` solved it. 
So it turns out that there is no problem with the `Table View/ Scroll View` located on a Y position different than 0 (in appose to what I read in another post, which also dealt with this problem).